# Searching and matching date columns of different spread sheets to copy the matched row into the first one

Tags: excel, vba

I'm more or less new in coding, just having some experience in Java.
For this specific purpose I think it's better to use VBA:
I have 2 Excel Sheets. In one are informations about the turnover of a specific shop and in the other are information about the weather on each day. To find correlations I'd like to join them. My Goal is to take the Date column of table 1 (see below), to look in table 2 for the matching date (because this is unique in table 2) und to copy the whole matching column from table 2 in table 1. I want to do this automatically for every row of table 1 to have all relevant data in that table.
Table1: 
**Date, ShopID, ProductID, Turnover** 

01.01.2016, 14, 5, 15.000$ 
02.01.2016, 14, 5, 2.000$
02.01.2016, 14, 6, 5.000$
03.01.2016, 14, 5, 3.000$
03.01.2016, 14, 1, 4.000$
04.01.2016, 14, 2, 1.000$

Table2: 
**StationId, Date, SunShining, AvgTemperature**

3, 01.01.2016, 4, 17 
3, 02.01.2016, 5, 19 
3, 03.01.2016, 6, 12 
3, 04.01.2016, 4, 14

How can I realise that ?

It's my first project, I would appreciate any help very much.

Comment: A simple VLOOKUP formula will do it.  Why vba?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

**Sheet 1:**

[image]

**Sheet 2**

[image]

In sheet 1, add the columns: StationID, SunShining, and AvgTemperature headers.
In Cell E1, Type use `INDEX` to get the values in the cells. The formula shall be as follows:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$D,MATCH(Sheet1!$A2,Sheet2!$B:$B,0),MATCH(Sheet1!E$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1,0))
```

Then drag the formula to fill in the rest of the cells.

The reason `INDEX` is used instead of `VLOOKUP` is the fact that the lookup value is in the 2nd column. `INDEX` will allow you to lookup data once a reference point is made, in this case, you are matching the date in Sheet1 Column A to the date in Sheet2 Column B to get the row number, then you match the headers in Sheet1 row 1 to the headers in Sheet2.

Note that if you change the headers names in any sheet, you will get a `#REF!` error.

I hope this helps.